# React-tooltip in table showing in cell instead

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tooltip

Hi so I have a table in react, trying to put a tooltip on a td (cell). But it appears instead as a new td(cell). Any suggestions what I'm missing or doing wrong.

```
import {Tooltip as ReactTooltip} from "react-tooltip";

<div className='card-body py-3'>
    <div className='table-responsive'>
       <table className='table table-row-bordered table-row-gray-100 align-middle gs-0 gy-3'>
           <thead>
              <tr className='fw-bolder text-muted'>
                 <th className='min-w-120px' >Case id</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               {dataArray && dataArray.map((item, index) => (
                  <tr key={index}>
                            <td>
                                <span id={`tooltip-${item.card_number}`} className='text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary fs-6 text-break'>{item.case_id.slice(0, 10)}</span>
                            </td>
                            <ReactTooltip
                                anchorId={`tooltip-${item.card_number}`}
                                place="bottom"
                                variant="info"
                                content="I'm a info tooltip"
                            />
                  </tr>
                ))}
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is how it apperas
As you can see in a new cell and not when I hower the Case id

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution!

1)
I was missing the css from react-tooltip

`import {Tooltip as ReactTooltip} from "react-tooltip";`

And as you can see I'm using bootstrap 5 and the class called "table" was was also interfering with the tooltip, so when I removed that class it worked.

2)
After that I found another solution to use bootstraps own tooltip css

```
<span title={item.case_id} data-toggle="tooltip" className='text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary fs-6 text-break'>{item.case_id.slice(0, 10)}</span>
```

You only need to put title="what you want your tooltip to say, when hovering" and data-toggle="tooltip.

The only bad thing about this it was showing the tooltip really oldschool css.

3)
After that I found a better solution. Bootstrap5 has it own tooptip import these

```
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger';
import Tooltip from 'react-bootstrap/Tooltip';
<td>
 <OverlayTrigger
     placement={'bottom'}
     overlay={
         <Tooltip id={`tooltip-${item.case_id}`}>
             {item.case_id}
         </Tooltip>
     }
 >
     <span className='text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary fs-6 text-break'>{item.case_id.slice(0, 10)}</span>
  </OverlayTrigger>
<td>
```